# How to inject an event handler dependency in .net 6?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, rabbitmq, event-handling, delegates

Hi im trying to create a logic for connect to RabbitMQ and manage events with generics class.

**My problem resume** : I dont know how to inject the class **NotificationEventHandler**

I have 3 classes:

**IEventHandler:**

```
public interface IEventHandler<T>
    where T : class
{
    Task StartListen();
}
```

**EventHandlerBase:** (Has the main listen to rabbit queue)

```
public abstract class EventHandlerBase<T> : IEventHandler<T>
    where T: class
{
    private readonly IEvent<T> _event;
    private readonly string _queueName;

    #region Event declarate
    public delegate Task EventCallBack<T>(T message);
    public event EventCallBack<T> HandleMessage;
    #endregion

    public EventHandlerBase(IEvent<T> @event)
    {
        _event = @event;
        _queueName = _event.Name;
        this.StartListen();
    }

    public async Task StartListen()
    {
        var consumer = new AsyncEventingBasicConsumer(_event.GetModel());
        consumer.Received += async (ch, ea) =>
        {
            var body = ea.Body.ToArray();
            var text = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);

            var objectValue = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(text);
            //Invoke declared event
            HandleMessage?.Invoke(objectValue);

            await Task.CompletedTask;
            _event.GetModel().BasicAck(ea.DeliveryTag, false);
        };

        _event.GetModel().BasicConsume(_queueName, false, "", false, false, null, consumer);
        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }

}
```

**NotificationEventHandler:** (Has concrete logic and susbscription to EventHandlerBase)

```
 public class NotificationEventHandler 
{
    public NotificationEventHandler(EventHandlerBase<NotificationDTO> eventHandler)
    {
        eventHandler.HandleMessage += this.MyHandleMessage;
    }

    public async Task MyHandleMessage(NotificationDTO message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Do something...");
    }
}
```

In **Program.cs:** injection (i dont know)

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IEventHandler<NotificationDTO>, EventHandlerBase<NotificationDTO>>();

builder.Services.AddSingleton<NotificationEventHandler<NotificationDTO>>(); // ???
```

NotificationDTO is any class with properties....

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to access NotificationDTO you will have to add generic typing to NotificationEventHandler like:

```cs
class NotificationEventHandler<T>
{
    public T Notification { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

And then notification would be of type NotificationDTO when you invoke it like NotificationEventHandler

Comment: But i need to inject NotificationEventHandler